# Compact linear operator on a separable Hilbert space is approximately of finite dimension

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

$X$ is a separable Hilbert space and $ A\in L(X,X)$ and compact.
I need to prove that $A$ is approximately of finite dimension.

Comment: Let $(e_i)$ be an orthonormal basis of $X$ and define $A_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n (Ax,e_i)e_i$. Show that $A_n\rightarrow A$ in $L(X,X)$. Note that since $A(B(X))$ has compact closure, given $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N$ such that $\sum_{i\ge N} |(Ax,e_i)|^2 <\epsilon$ for all $x$ with $\vert x\Vert\le1$.

Comment: What is the B(X)?

Comment: The closed unit ball of $X$ (elements of norm at most one).

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon>0$, let $\mathcal N$ be a finite $\epsilon$-net in $A(B_X)$, where $B_X$  is the closed unit ball of $X$. Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto the linear span of $\mathcal{N}$. By construction, $\|Py-y\|\le \epsilon$ for all $y\in A(B_X)$. Hence, $\|PA-A\|\le \epsilon$. Since $PA$ has finite rank and $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we are done.

As an aside, I prefer "is the norm limit of finite-rank operators" to "is approximately of finite dimension"; the former being more descriptive.